# Find in object to Edit or Add

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

I have an object `productCounts`

```
[{provisioned=2.0, product=str1, totalID=1.0}, 
 {product=str2, provisioned=4.0, totalID=3.0}, 
 {provisioned=6.0, product=str3, totalID=5.0}]
```

I have an array `uniqueProduct`

```
[str1, str2, str3, str4]
```

I am then looping a dataset to get the totalID count, add it to the product's totalID but if it doesn't exist, push it to the object.

```
var countID = 0;

uniqueProduct.forEach(
  currentproduct => {
    countID = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < shtRng.length; ++i) {
      if (shtRng[i][ProductCol].toString() == currentproduct) { // && shtRng[i][IDcol].toString().length>4){
        countID++;
      }
    }
    if (countID == 0) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(currentproduct + ": " + countID);
  }
)
```

This works perfectly to return the countID per product in `uniqueProduct`

Rather than logging the result, I would like to add it to the object like this... If the current unique product is not in the `productCounts` object, add it.

```
let obj = productCounts.find((o, i) => {
    if (o.product == currentproduct) {
        productCounts[i] = { product: currentproduct, totalID: productCounts[i].totalID+countID, provisioned: productCounts[i].provisioned };
        return true;
    } else {
        productCounts.push({ product: currentproduct, totalID: countID, provisioned: 0 });
        return true;
    }
});
```

In my head, this should work but it appears to skip some records or add the product multiple times. How do I add to the object correctly?

Expected output is the object to be something similar to:

[{provisioned=2.0, product=str1, totalID=35.0},
{product=str2, provisioned=4.0, totalID=8.0},
{provisioned=6.0, product=str3, totalID=51.0},
{provisioned=6.0, product=str4, totalID=14.0}]

Comment: Please add a comment if voting to close. I've got my example and what I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `find()` is a function that returns a boolean when the element matches the criteria. The `if` statement should use the result of this, it shouldn't be in the condition function.

```
let obj = productCounts.find(o => o.product == currentProduct);
if (obj) {
    obj.totalId += countID;
} else {
    productCounts.push(productCounts.push({ product: currentproduct, totalID: countID, provisioned: 0 });
}
```

BTW, your life would be easier if you used an object whose keys are the product names, rather than an array of objects. You can easily turn the array of objects into such an object:

```
let productCountsObj = Object.fromEntries(productCounts.map(o => [o.product, o]));
if (currentProduct in productCountsObj) {
    productCountsObj[currentProduct].totalID += countID;
} else {
    productCountsObj[currentProduct] = { product: currentproduct, totalID: countID, provisioned: 0 };
}
```